# DAX: how to ignore slicer for particular measure

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, measure

**Data model** & dashboard:

[image]

**Intention**: to prevent table visual from resizing due to slicing

**Desired outcome:**

[image]

[**Link** to .pbi:](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/tree/main/Questions)

**P.S.** Tons of videos watched, but still can't resolve...

Of course in real life model is a bit more complicated.

Currently have to use dirty workaround which includes copy of Id column related with original one with unnatural 1:N relationship (to prevent filtering) and measure with `selectedvalue` for `Num` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sort of skirting the generally intended behavior of slicers, so this isn't quite as simple as you might think it ought to be.

To do this, create a new disconnected parameter table for the IDs:

```
dimID = VALUES(Table1[Id])
```

Use this new table for your slicer and write a measure that reads these values.

```
SumNum =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[Num] ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( Table1[Id] IN VALUES ( dimID[Id] ) )
)
```

Put this in your table and it should behave as expected provided you set 'Show items with no data' on the Table1[Id] column.

[image: Menu screenshot]

Result:

[image: Result screenshot]

Comment: Alexis, Thank you so much for this wonderful Christmas gift! For me, as for new DAXer, when you see the working solution, code looks obvious and easy to read. But, unfortunately, not as easy to write... ;) 

As far as I remember I tried something similar but without separate `dimID`, like `...KEEPFILTERS ( Table1[Id] IN VALUES (ALL(Table1,Table1[Id]))...`

But it didn't pass even syntax check...